# What is the meaning of this Church numeral example?

Tags: lambda-calculus

There is an example of Church numeral, on the secion `Encoding Datatypes` of `lambda calculus`'s wikipedia [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus).

> One way of thinking about the Church numeral n, which is often useful
>   when analysing programs, is as an instruction 'repeat n times'. For
>   example, using the PAIR and NIL functions defined below, one can
>   define a function that constructs a (linked) list of n elements all
>   equal to x by repeating 'prepend another x element' n times, starting
>   from an empty list. The lambda term is
>
> λn.λx.n (PAIR x) NIL By varying what is being repeated, and varying
>   what argument that function being repeated is applied to, a great many
>   different effects can be achieved.
>
> By varying what is being repeated, and varying what argument that
>   function being repeated is applied to, a great many different effects
>   can be achieved.
>
> We can define a successor function, which takes a Church numeral n and
>   returns n + 1 by adding another application of f, where '(mf)x' means
>   the function 'f' is applied 'm' times on 'x':
>
> SUCC := λn.λf.λx.f (n f x)

I don't understand what the `PAIR` , `NIL` and `SUCC` means right now. Since "the PAIR and NIL functions" are "defined below", let's skip them for now and consider `SUCC`.

What the `SUCC` means here? Does it mean `success`, `succeed` or something else?

I am trying to use Scheme language to define `SUCC`:

```
(define succ
  (lambda (n)
    (lambda (f)
      (lambda (x)
        (f ((n f) x))))))
```

Am I right? If so, what can this `succ` function do? If not, what is the right definition, and what can it do?

Can you give me some example to explain this? If I can understand `SUCC` I think I can understand `PLUS` which defined just below it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The word `succ` means *successor*; informally, the successor of a natural number $n \in \mathbb N$ is the natural number $n + 1$.

Church numerals are one way to represent the natural numbers. The natural number $n \in \mathbb N$ is represented as the function which takes as its argument another function $f$, and returns the $n$-fold composite
$$
\underbrace{f \circ f \circ \cdots \circ f}_{n \text{ times}}.
$$
Thus, we have for example that $3(f) = f \circ f \circ f$, or in a more lambda calculus notation we have:

```
3 f = f . f . f
```

Or, a "non-point-free" version:

```
(3 f) x = f (f (f x))
```

As special cases we have that `0 f = id` (or `(0 f) x = x`) and `1 f = f` (or `(1 f) x = f x`).

Now the successor function has to take a natural number (Church numeral) $n$, and return $n + 1$; thus, it has to take a function which turns functions into their $n$-fold composite, and return a function which turns functions into their $n+1$-fold composite. (There are a lot of layers here, so try thinking about this until it starts to make sense to you.)

The way this is implemented is that it takes a natural number, `n`, and the resulting thing has to take a function, `f`, and the resulting thing should be the $n+1$-fold composition of $f$ -- that is, it should take an $x$ and return
$$
\underbrace{f(f( \cdots f(x) \cdots ))}_{n+1 \text{ applications}}.
$$
In yet other words, it should return `f ((n f) x)`.

This is precisely the code you wrote:

```
(define succ               #Define function succ, which
  (lambda (n)              #Takes a natural number n, returns a function which
    (lambda (f)            #Takes a function and returns its n+1 fold composite:
      (lambda (x)          #It takes an x and applies f n + 1 times, namely
        (f ((n f) x))))))  #It applies f to "f applied n times to x".
```

Comment: That is exactly what I didn't understand. I feel enlightened. Thank you very much.

Comment: It looks similiar to something that I have learnt in the Abstract Algebra course.